# What might cause hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException

Tags: content-delivery

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 with Websphere 8.5. Recently we started getting this kind of exception when querying the broker:

> org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
>       at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:254)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:87)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.(SessionImpl.java:227)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1636)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getRawSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:120)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.setDefaultProperties(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:267)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:179)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.(EntityManagerImpl.java:89)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:120)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:517)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.createEntityManager(Unknown Source)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.getEntityManager(JPABaseDAO.java:53)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:264)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:249)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQueryListResult(JPABaseDAO.java:220)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.executeQuerySingleResult(JPABaseDAO.java:199)
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAItemDAO.findByPrimaryKey(JPAItemDAO.java:218)
>       at com.tridion.storage.caching.CachedItemDAO.findByPrimaryKey(CachedItemDAO.java:67)
>       at com.tridion.storage.caching.CachedItemDAO.findByPrimaryKey(CachedItemDAO.java:83)
>       at com.tridion.meta.ComponentMetaFactory.getMeta(ComponentMetaFactory.java:105)
>       at com.deltalloyd.dlva.dao.impl.NewsDAOImpl.getSortedComponentMetasList(NewsDAOImpl.java:190)
>       at com.deltalloyd.dlva.dao.impl.NewsDAOImpl.findLast(NewsDAOImpl.java:120)
>       at com.deltalloyd.dlva.tridion.taglib.NewsCollection.doTag(NewsCollection.java:54)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspx_meth_bus_newscollection_0(_index.java:1477)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index.access$0(_index.java:1465)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index$_indexHelper.invoke0(_index.java:3264)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index$_indexHelper.invoke(_index.java:3313)
>       at com.deltalloyd.dlva.tridion.taglib.CacheTag.doTag(CacheTag.java:38)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspx_meth_bus_cache_0(_index.java:1897)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._index._jspService(_index.java:398)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:220)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>       at com.deltalloyd.dlva.filters.NewsArticleFilter.doFilter(NewsArticleFilter.java:55)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3923)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1006)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)

I think the relevant part of this message is the following:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:517) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.createEntityManager(Unknown Source) at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.getEntityManager(JPABaseDAO.java:53) at

It seems that the Tridion JPABaseDAO relies on Spring to get an "entity manager", but that something goes wrong in the EntityManagerFactory. Presumably there is a configuration setting somewhere that controls this behaviour.

Restarting the web application makes the problem disappear for a while, but not permanently.

What can cause this problem? What is the best strategy for solving it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a database access exception, it most likely means you either don't have your broker configured correctly (could be direct database connection OR your items) or your websphere datasource isn't configured correctly.